# Dicionario para lista de dicionários

Tags: python

Eu tenho um dicionario como a seguinte:

```
{'Eva': [4], 'Ana': [53], 'Ada': [12]}
```

E pretendo transformar numa lista de dicionarios neste tipo :

```
[{'Nome do Dono': 'Eva', 'Media de idades' : '4'},{'Nome do Dono':'Ana':'Media das Idades':'53'},{'Nome do Dono': 'Ada', 'Media de idades' : '12'}]
```

Podem ajudar de como obter a lista de dicionarios como pretendo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obter a lista de dicionários faça assim:

```
dict_1 = {'Eva': [4], 'Ana': [53], 'Ada': [12]}  
lista_dict = [{'Media de Idade':idade.pop(), 'Nome do Dono':nome} for nome, idade in dict_1.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que você tenha obtido o valor 4,666 a partir da divisão de 28 por 6, você pode usar a função [ceil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) para efetuar o arredondamento:

```
import math

age_avg = 28 / 6.0 # 4.666666666666667
print age_avg # imprime 4.666666666666667
print math.ceil(age_avg) # imprime 5
```